# How to make a string exercise into int in kotlin?

Tags: string, kotlin, text, integer, calculator

Everything I tried gives an Error, it can handle the numbers but not the "+",what I want is the result to be "10". I'm attempting to make a calculator in android studio...
This is what I tried:

```
var sum = "5+5"
val num = sum.toInt()
exercise.text = "$num" //the text displayed on the screen
```

Comment: where does "5+5" come from?

Comment: I mean technically you're hoping there's already a calculator built into the `toInt` call, which there isn't! If you want to parse a string as a set of numbers and operations, that's kinda complicated, but doable if you keep it simple (you'd be better finding a tutorial on it though if you're a beginner). If you want to actually make a typical calculator app, you'd be storing button presses instead, not holding the whole thing as a string and trying to work out what it means at the end

Comment: cactustictacs, you're right! thank you for fixing my thinking process! I might try that, but I'm attempting to start coding with no tutorials because I often get into a tutorial loop or "hell" if you will and can't find my own way of doing things.

Comment: Mathematical expressions would need to be parsed.  If you want to learn how to write a parser, they're probably a very good place to start, as the language is fairly simple and well-understood!  Otherwise, you'd need to find a library you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed a tutorial and I can now answer my own question:
You can use implementation 'net.objecthunter:exp4j:0.4.8' in your build gradle, then use .append(string) to add a string into your text and then use

```
val expression = ExpressionBuilder(Text.text.toString()).build()
val result = expression.evaluate()
val longResult = result.toLong()
if(result == longResult.toDouble())
   Text.text = "=$longResult"
else
    Text.text = "=$result"
```

to evaluate and paste the result in the text you have

Answer (score 1):

Use `eval` function insted of `toInt()` , just a little research [See](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/eval.html)

*Above is only available for Kotlin/Js.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be sure to try that!

Comment: Note the big scary warning in the linked docs about how that “is an enormous security risk”.  A hand-written or library parser would be far safer — and probably a lot faster too.

Comment: but op wants to build a calculator!